# Having trouble with cookie operation with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

This works:

```
var d = new Date();
document.cookie = name + "=1;expires=" + d.toGMTString() + ";" + "; path=/";
```

But this doesn't work:

```
function deletecookie(name)
{
    var d = new Date();
    document.cookie = name + "=1;expires=" + d.toGMTString() + ";" + "; path=/";
}
deletecookie(name);
```

Why it doesn't work after wrapping in a function?

**EDIT**

Seems this only happens in firebug,is there some reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in latest version of Firefox so long as you define name before hand:

```
<script>
var name="hello"
function deletecookie(name)
{
    var d = new Date();
    document.cookie = name + "=1;expires=" + d.toGMTString() + ";" + "; path=/";
document.write(name);
}
deletecookie(name);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebug often causes all sorts of bugs. Try its latest version and if the problem persists, [see this](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!).